# How can i check if a particular process is a critical process?

Tags: c++

How can i check if a particular process is a critical process, like csrss.exe and smss.exe?

Comment: Get the user of the process, if it's `SYSTEM` it's probably more important than others.

Comment: There's no way to do that using standard c++ features.

Comment: [IsProcessCritical](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180216-00/?p=98035) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Have a read of: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180216-00/?p=98035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [NtQueryInformationProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess) function and ProcessBreakOnTerminate in the second parameter, if the process is critical the return in buffer will be a value greater than 0, otherwise the value is 0.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that MSDN encourages the use of `IsProcessCritical` rather than `NtQueryInformationProcess(hProc, ProcessBreakOnTerminate, ...) `.
_Note This value can be used starting in Windows XP with SP3. Starting in Windows 8.1, IsProcessCritical should be used instead._